# Activar depuración en modo Release en Android

Tags: android-studio, depuración

Automáticamente Android-Studio desactiva el sistema de log cuando tienes el sabor seleccionado a `release`, pero si necesitas depurar la versión final.

¿Cómo se puede forzar la activación y poder obtener los `log` del programa?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

En tu AndroidManifest.xml agrega

```
android:debuggable="true"
```

Un poco curioso pero en mi caso y solo en una pc al abrir el ADM aún estando en `release` me los muestra, suponía que esto era el comportamiento normal.

Comment: A mi si lo pongo en release me los bloquea todos, debe ser algo de configuración del lint, pero con eso en aplication me ha servidor